# is it possible to load class information via JMX?

Tags: java, reflection, classpath, jmx

I have two JAVA programms A,B which are communicating via JMX.
Programm A has a class X in his classpath but B doens't have it. But i want to instantiate it in B via reflection. is this even possible to transfer that class from A to B via JMX? And if it is how could i do it?

Comment: Why not include the class X or the jar containing class X in the classpath of application B?

Comment: It's not that i just need that information about that particular class X. There can be Hundrets of different X's from hundrets of different A's.

Comment: Is the program "A" an actual MBean registered in the JMX MBeanServer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transfer the bytes of the .class, cache and then load from disk.. I haven't tried it so there maybe some issues but might be worth a try.

Comment: Where you able to do it?. I'm trying to ask the path of the jar that contains class X, so I'll be able to load it. (both programms in the same system)